# Async Operations inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Like you see above, when the event `pause` triggers I wan to do a bunch of operations in asynchronous way. But if I do like this, I think the callback of `addon` will never return.

```
//(...)
client.on('stream', function(stream, meta) {
    //(....)
    stream.on('pause', function () { 
        addon.calculate_results_async(stream, client.id, function(results, stream) {
            stream.write(results); //send the results
        });
    });
});
```

First, am I right about the beahviour of the addon? And second, If I am right how can I `calculate_results_async` in this context?

Comment: Have you tested to see if you're right about the behavior?  Is it throwing an error, or unusual results?

Comment: @TbWill4321 I have not tested yet. I am trying to predict the behavior of this implementation before change what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems error happened at async operation.

```
Promise.all([your stuff]).then(function() {
  // all loaded
}, function() {
  // one or more failed
});
```

Or

You may forgot resolve a promise in your async

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```